# ¿Cómo referenciar la Connection String de una dll en vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Tengo un caso peculiar, actualmente tengo una dll quien usa una connection string "connString" definida principalmente por el app.config del **ProyectoDLL**, la cual la mando a llamar en un dataset o un archivo "dataset.xsd".

Al compilarla, me genera un archivo "nombre.dll.config", el cual no usaré, y en su caso, definiré la connection string "connString" dentro de **otro proyecto** con **otro ambiente** al cual insertaré la dll, para que el **"dataset.xsd"** se conecte a la nueva "connString" definida.

*El problema* es el siguiente, cuando compilo la dll, quito dentro de las opciones avanzadas de compilación el "Generate debug info" lo seteo en None y coloco la "nombre.dll" y "nombre.xml".

Pero siempre me sigue tomando la configuración del Connection String del **ProyectoDLL**, pero quiero que tome la Connection String "connString" del **otro proyecto**.

*Mi pregunta es,* ¿Tengo que modificar alguna parte del designer del DataSet?, tendré que setearle que vaya a tomar la configuración de cualquier app.config independientemente el proyecto?.

Agradezco de antemano sus respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por si les funciona, encontré la solución:
Dentro del proyecto dll al mandar a llamar el tableadapter por ejemplo:

```
Dim adapter As New TablasTableAdapters.TablaTableAdapter
adapter.Connection.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("connString").ToString()
```

Esto me asegura que cuando pase a otro proyecto, se adapte a la nueva referencia del app.config y le setee los nuevos parámetros.